# To compare two KL-divergence scores, does the prior model have to be the same for both?

Tags: model-selection, information-theory, model-comparison, kullback-leibler, divergence

The KL-divergence compares a theoretical model $p$'s distribution with the empirical model $q$'s distribution, giving a score of $0$ if they, or their information contents, are identical.

Say we have two KL-divergences for two distinct models (that have the same units and context), therefore two pairs (4) distributions

1. If the first score $KLD_1=0.3$ tells us how far off model 1 ($p_1$) is in reality from theoretical model 1 ($q_1$),
2. and the second score $KLD_2=0.4$ quantifies how far off model 2 is in reality ($p_2$) from theoretical model 2 ($q_2$),

can I compare the values of $KLD_1$ and $KLD_2$ directly and conclude "model 1 outperformed model 2 because its score was lower, implying less divergence from *its own* theoretical prior" even though the scores were respectively measured based on two different models/priors? Or are two KLD scores only comparable if based on **the same** underlying theoretical model, i.e. $(p_1 || \mathbf{q_1})$ vs $(p_2 || \mathbf{q_1})$?

The question more abstractly,

1. KLD(red apples || green apples) vs KLD(red grapes ||  green grapes), or
2. KLD(red apples || **mangos**) vs KLD(red grapes || **mangos**)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible but chances are it is not the kind of performance you had in mind originally. Essentially, you are saying *using model 1's predicted distribution to encode information about the "true" distribution 1 is more efficient than using model 2's predicted distribution to encode information about the "true" distribution 2*.

This statement makes no claim about the predictive ability of either model. A model that predicts an ideal coin flip with odds of 50:50 will be right about as often as it is wrong and will have KLD = 0. Contrast this with a model that predicts that I will always eat a red apple that I bought. It will be right more often than it will be wrong (I do eat most of the apples that I buy), but sometimes I give the apple to my girlfriend instead, so the model doesn't match the "true" distribution and hence KLD > 0. Which of the two models makes better predictions?

Additionally, the models predict different things, so there is no reason to prefer one over the other; we can happily use both in tandem.